# React sortable tree does not respect treeIndex order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tree

I am trying to persist the order of Nodes in the tree using react-sortable-tree (https://github.com/frontend-collective/react-sortable-tree), for Example

```
 - Label 1
      - Label 2
      - Label 3
```

Changing the order of Label 3 to Label 2 in the following way and also passing the treeIndex,

```
 - Label 1
      - Label 3
      - Label 2
```

Upon setting the updated state and reloading the page tree structure does not follow treeIndex order.

#### **Things I have tried:**

I have tried the following using the utils of react sortable tree (https://github.com/frontend-collective/react-sortable-tree/blob/master/src/utils/tree-data-utils.js)

I have tried converting my current tree to flat structure using `getFlatDataFromTree()` and then making the treeIndex changes that are required and then converting the flat data back to tree structure using the same util library with `getTreeFromFlatData()` but the sequence with respect to treeIndex is not considered.

I already have tree data stored in treeData,

here labelNodes contain the path of each node of the tree. So I am looping over them and assigning the correct order.

Code:

```js
flatTree.forEach(treeNode => {
        labelNodes.forEach(element => {
          if (treeNode.node.id === element.id) {
            treeNode.path = element.path;
            treeNode.treeIndex = element.treeIndex;
          }
          return true;
        });
      });

const getParentKey = node => {
        if (node.parentNode) {
          return node.parentNode.id;
        }
        return 0;
      };

const sortedFlatTree = flatTree.sort((a, b) => a.treeIndex - b.treeIndex);

const treeConversion = getTreeFromFlatData({
        flatData: sortedFlatTree,
        getParentKey,
      });
```

treeConversion does not maintain the sorted order.

Comment: Post your code. Are you using only the local state ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have posted my code for reference @SanishJoseph